# Writing char array to binary file with specific encoding

Tags: qt

How can I write char array to binary file with CP-1251 encoding using Qt 4.7.2?

Following code doesn't work, it saves array in UTF-8 encoding:

```
QTextCodec* codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1251");
QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(codec);

char* str = "абвгд";

ofstream out("/home/ivan/Binary/moo.bin");
out << str;
out.close();
```

Upd: solution has been found. :>

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8")); // Set encoding for QObject::tr
QTextCodec* codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1251") ; // Set encoding for result data in file
QByteArray bytes = codec->fromUnicode(QObject::tr("Текст на русском языке")); // Encode data in cp-1251


// Write data to binary file
ofstream out("/home/ivan/Binary/moo.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
out.write(bytes.constData(), bytes.size());
out.close();
```

Works fine on ubuntu 11.04, eng

Comment: there is QTextCodec::fromUnicode() which QByteArray, you can try storing that into file.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using Qt here at all.  `QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings` determines how QString reads `char *`, and certainly can't control how the standard library chooses to write text.

If you do want to do this with Qt, use QTextStream and set the appropriate codec on it.